# Proper insertion of table name

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

How does one correctly provide the table name if the name can be dynamically determined and still prevent SQL injection attacks? I am using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

For example:

The following works but I believe is insecure:

```
dbclient.query("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [value_a, value_b, value_c])`
```

What I would like equivalently (but does not work) is:

```
dbclient.query("INSERT INTO $1 VALUES ($2, $3, $4)", [table_name, value_a, value_b, value_c])`
```

Comment: according to https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1426, it's not possible in postgres

Answer (score 2):

Any good library should provide proper escaping for SQL names, which include:

- schema name
- table name
- column name

For example, within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) you would use it like this:

```
db.query("INSERT INTO $1~ VALUES ($2, $3, $4)", [table_name, value_a, value_b, value_c])
```

i.e. you get your table name properly escaped by appending the variable with `~`, which in turn makes it safe from SQL injection.

From [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/formatting.js#L319), a simple escaping for table names executed by the library:

```
return '"' + name.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
```

See also: [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names)

Answer (score 0):

You might manually check the validity if table name with a regex some other validation logic. I would probably use a dictionary containing permissible table names.

```
var tables = {users:'users', boats:'boats'};
table_name = tables[table_name];
if (! table_name) throw new Error();
dbclient.query("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [value_a, value_b, value_c])
```

If you plan on generating a lot of dynamic sql, use a query builder like http://knexjs.org/

Comment: I recommend you instead use `table_name = tables.hasOwnProperty(table_name) ? tables[table_name] : null` - without the `hasOwnProperty` check a user could supply, for example, `table_name = 'toString'`, which would cause an unexpected error.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a hash `let tables = {tableName1: 'table_name1', tableName2: 'table_name2'...}` and then

```
//assuming you receive t as table name input
if(tables[t])
  //build SQL query with tables[t] as the table name
else
  //throw error about non-existing table
```

This way, you control the actual table names in the DB.

Also, do not forget to **clean all input** - the values may contain injections.

Comment: What would injection attacks look like against this kind of existing hash lookup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `escape` function from `pg-escape` npm module to quote identifiers such as table names:

### Only using escape function:

```
escape("INSERT INTO %I VALUES (%L, %L, %L)", table_name, value_a, value_b, value_c);
```

### Combine it with node postgres:

```
dbclient.query(escape("INSERT INTO %I VALUES ($2, $3, $4)", table_name), [value_a, value_b, value_c]);
```