# PostgreSQL: Parameter substitution for LISTEN?

Tags: postgresql, security, sql-injection

Common sense dictates that SQL query strings should **never** be assembled by hand. Thus, all database interfaces offer parameter substitution, and all users use it, without exceptions.*

I'm using PostgreSQL v10.5, nodejs v8.12.0, node-postgres 7.6.1.

Parameter substitution works as expected for `SELECT` statements:

```
> await db.query("select from users where id = 'mic'");
(success, 1 row returned)
> await db.query("select from users where id = $1", ["mic"]);
(success, 1 row returned)
```

But it doesn't work for `LISTEN` statements:

```
> await db.query("listen topicname");
(success)
> await db.query("listen $1", ["topicname"]);
(error: syntax error at or near "$1")
```

The name of the topic I want to listen to is dynamic. It is coming from semi-trustworthy sources, which should not be user-controllable. But why go against all established best practice and take any chances?

Unfortunately, from my tests I fear that PostgreSQL simply can't do parameter substitution for `LISTEN` queries.

Is there any solution or workaround for this?

*) This statement may only be true in some utopic future society.

Comment: See [Proper insertion of table name.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687311/1995738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this cannot be done in PostgreSQL.

As a workaround, write a PL/pgSQL function that uses [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) like this:

```
EXECUTE format('LISTEN %L', topicname);
```

The [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function escapes strings properly; in this case, the `%L` format that produces a properly quoted string **L**iteral is the appropriate one.

Comment: Why `%L`? Does it ensure safe escaping?

Comment: Yes; I have added another line and a link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer, but the proposed solution doesn't work for me.
Using `%L` results in a quoted string, which causes the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'topic'"
```

The `%I` format should be used instead (SQL identifier, this is documented for table and column names, but it also works for the channel name,). You can also use the `quote_ident` function. See the documentation on creating dynamic queries [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE).

The following PL/pgSQL function works for us:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listenForChannel(
    channel_   TEXT
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('LISTEN %I', channel_);
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```